# SSRS - Specify chart interval

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In SSRS, I have a bar chart that looks as follows:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5ETs.png)

How can I force the chart label to show  -10%, 0%, 10%, 20%, etc?

Thank you.

I tried setting the "LabelInterval" property to various values.
For the "Axis Options", enabled "logarithmetic scale" and set value to 10

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  I set the "Axis Options" in the "Horizontal Axis Properties" for the minimum and maximum to something that is divisible by 10 and afterwards set the "Label Interval" to 0.1

Comment: Thats the correct way. You would set the max axis value to be something like `=(CINT((MAX(Fields!myField.Value, "mydatasetname") / 10))+1)*10 ` where 10 is the interval you want and a similar things with the min, adjusting for negative values.